# Problemas com o perfil do usuario

Tags: php

O resulta do desta página da erro:

> Notice: Undefined variable: nome in C:\xampp\htdocs\Techphp\perfil.php
>   on line 57,  line 58,   line 59 e    line 60,

Que são as linha onde estão os dados do perfil do usuário.

O que não entendo porque esta dando esse resultado.
Será que não esta conectado?

```
<?php 
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "angola") or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("login_senha");


session_start();
$login =  $_SESSION['login_usuario'];

$login =  $_SESSION['login_usuario']=$login;
$sql = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE  login='$login'");
while($linha= mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $nome=$linha['nome']; 
    $email=$linha['email'];
    $idade=$linha['idade'];
    $cidade=$linha['cidade'] ;
    $foto=$linha['foto'] ;

}
?>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Techphp/css/estilo.css"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Techphp/css/estilo.css"/>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="index.php">Voltar</a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="#">Administração</a>

        </li>

    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="perfil">

      <img src="fotos/<?php echo $foto?>" alt="imagem de perfil" title="imagem de perfil"  />
    </div>

    <div class="dados">
        <p>Nome</p><p><?php echo $nome?></p>    
        <p>Email</p><p><?php echo $email?></p>
        <p>idade</p><p>40<?php echo $idade?></p>    
        <p>Cidade</p><p><?php echo $cidade?></p>

    </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Conseguiu resolver Bruno?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode elaborar da seguinte forma:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "angola") or die("cannot connect");
    mysql_select_db("login_senha");

    $login = $_SESSION['login_usuario'];
    $sql = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE  login='{$login}'");
    $linha = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Techphp/css/estilo.css"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Techphp/css/estilo.css"/>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="index.php">Voltar</a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="#">Administração</a>

        </li>

    </ul>
    </div>
    <?
    if(mysql_num_rows($sql)>0){
    ?>
    <div class="perfil">
      <img src="fotos/<?php echo $linha['foto']; ?>" alt="imagem de perfil" title="imagem de perfil"  />
    </div>
    <div class="dados">
        <p>Nome</p><p><?php echo $linha['nome']; ?></p>    
        <p>Email</p><p><?php echo $linha['email'];?></p>
        <p>idade</p><p>40<?php echo $linha['idade'];?></p>    
        <p>Cidade</p><p><?php echo $linha['cidade'];?></p>
    </div>
    <? } else {  ?>
     <div class="perfil">
        Este usuário não está logado ou não foi encontrado.
     </div>
    <? } ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Lembrando que o Login está vindo da `session`, procure verificar também a senha dele, pra ver se bate com a senha registrada, mas neste caso ele já está logado? Não entendi bem... Mas tente elaborar conforme minha sugestão.

Comment: ok,farei essas mudanças agradeço de coração

Comment: Ok! Qualquer coisa deixe-nos saber!

Comment: ok qualquer duvida darei noticias

Comment: Foi executado nesta ordem mas ele aparece com a seguinte noticia: Notice: Undefined index: login_usuario in C:\xampp\htdocs\Techphp\perfil.php on line 6 isto não entendi ate porque na pagina logar esta a  $login = $_SESSION['login_usuario']; não estou entendendo o que eta errado na index da linha 6 onde esta registrada : $login = $_SESSION['login_usuario'];

Comment: De onde você está buscando o Login? Ele normalmente vem por session ou post ou get?

Comment: ele esta no no post:  $login = $_POST['login'];

Comment: Então, só altere $login = $_SESSION['login_usuario']; para $login = $_POST['login'];

Comment: agora ele me mostra o erro na linha 8: Notice: Undefined variable: login in C:\xampp\htdocs\Techphp\perfil.php on line 8:   $sql = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE  login='{$login}'");

Comment: Troque $sql = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE login='{$login}'"); por $sql = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE login='{$login}'") or print mysql_error();

Comment: obs:desculpe eu errei na linha ainda continua erro na linha 6 :Notice: Undefined index: login in C:\xampp\htdocs\Techphp\perfil.php on line 6: onde esta o  $login = $_POST['login'];

Comment: vou te mandar todo o processo das paginas ok,

Comment: Ok, coloque aqui na sua pergunta.

Comment: ok vou mandar  na pergunta

Answer (score 0):

Troque este trecho:

```
$login =  $_SESSION['login_usuario'];

$login =  $_SESSION['login_usuario']=$login;
```

Por este:

```
if( !isset($_SESSION['login_usuario']))
   die('Usuario nao logado');

$login = $_SESSION['login_usuario'];
```

E troque este trecho:

```
$sql = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE  login='$login'");
```

Por este:

```
$sql = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE  login='$login'");
if(mysql_num_rows($sql) == 0 )
 die('O usuario '.$login.' não existe');
```

Já vai resolver, ou no mínimo te ajudar a entender o próprio codigo.